# WooCommerce: Conditional Tag for Wishlist Page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using this plugin **YITH WooCommerce Wishlist** now I want to excute some code on wishlistpage how can i do this

for other pages i have used conditional tags list **is_home() , is_product_category()** etc is there any conditional tag for wishlist page please help me out..

Comment: May be `is_page('PAGE_ID')`, if you are trying specific to plugin then this is not the correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the Wishlist Page were all the wishlist items of a user are displayed, then actually its a single page so you could use is_page() function and pass the ID / slug of that page and then use it as a conditional tag to execute some code.